# How to remove ip and other numeric value while create temp file in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am getting a file name like `name` below. I want to remove the final ip and another numeric value to get finally the real file name. Is there any better way to achieve this than using regex? Maybe some other techniques? Please help me to know this.

```
        String name = "pdf_of_filename_127.10.10.0_8726347.xls";

        System.out.println("Initial File Name :"+name);

        String [] t = name.split("_");
        String finalpart = t[t.length - 1];
        String extension = finalpart.substring(finalpart.lastIndexOf("."),finalpart.length());

        String finalName = "";

        for(int i = 0;i < t.length - 2;i++)
            finalName += t[i]+"_";
        finalName = finalName.substring(0,finalName.length() - 1);

        System.out.println("Final File Name :"+finalName+extension);
```

**output:**

```
Initial File Name :pdf_of_filename_127.10.10.0_8726347.xls

Final File Name :pdf_of_filename.xls
```

**For more understanding :**

```
String name = "pdf_of_filename_53613785621.183761237_127.10.10.0_8726347.xls";

output Expected:
Final File Name :pdf_of_filename_53613785621.183761237.xls
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
String name = "pdf_of_filename_53613785621.183761237_127.10.10.0_8726347.xls";
String finalName = name.replaceAll("_(\\d+\\.){3}[\\d_]+","");
System.out.println("finalName = " + finalName);
```

which removes a substring that looks like:

```
_             an underscore
(\\d+\\.){3}  followed by 3 times a digit and a period (127.10.10.)
[\\d_]+       then some digits and underscores (0_876347)
```

Comment: thanks for  your reply but if the filename has some other "." and numeric values those things also remove if I use your code please help me.                                                      Initial File Name :pdf_of_filename_53613785621.183761237_127.10.10.0_8726347.xls       
Final File Name :pdf_of_filename_53613785621.183761237.xls                      
finalName = pdf_of_filename.xls

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
name = name.replaceAll("_[\\d._]+\\.",".");
```

**EDIT for new requirement in question**

try:

```
name = name.replaceAll("_\\d{1,3}\.[\\d._]+\\.",".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Safe RegEx to validate a filename ending in an IP, any number of digits and a file extension 3 to 4 letters long:

```
^(.*)_[12]?\d{1,2}\.[12]?\d{1,2}\.[12]?\d{1,2}\.[12]?\d{1,2}_\d+\.([a-z]{3,4})$
```

Replace with: `\1.\2`
Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/tE3iB8

Shorter: `^(.*)_([12]?\d{1,2}\.){3}[12]?\d{1,2}_\d+\.([a-z]{3,4})$`
Replace with: `\1.\3`
Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/rM6mD8